# How to display spinning wheel while going through all updating routines?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working on some mobile project written on Xamarin.Forms. And I have a problem here. I need to update my listview containing some data. So I enabled `IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true` and

```
listView.Refreshing += (sender, e) => {
    method1();

    method2();

    listView.EndRefresh();
};
```

However, I'm not sure, how to make spinning indicator showing until all updating routines are done.

```
public class Class1 : ContentPage
{
    readonly Class2 mangr = new Class2();
    void BuildUI()
    {
        listView = new ListView
        {
            ItemsSource = new object[] { },
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(listRender.MakeCell),

            RowHeight = 88,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,

            IsPullToRefreshEnabled = true,
            IsRefreshing = false,
        };

        listView.Refreshing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            listView.IsRefreshing = true;

            manager.ForceUpdate();

            listView.IsRefreshing = false;
            listView.EndRefresh();
        };
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public bool updating = false;

    public void PleaseUpdate()
    {
        if (!running)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!data.loading)
        {
            updating = true; 
            PleaseUpdate();
            updating = false;
        }
    }
    void PleaseUpdate(Action afterall = null){/some code/}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the PullToRefresh ActivityIndicator? For that you have to set the `IsRefreshing` property to `true`. So just set it to `true` at the beginning and to `false` whenever you're ready, like this.

```
listView.Refreshing += (sender, e) =>  { 
    listView.IsRefreshing = true;

    method1();

    method2();

    listView.IsRefreshing = false;
    listView.EndRefresh();
};
```

This will not work if the methods are `async` because it will go directly to the `IsRefreshing = false`.

There are multiple ways to go about this, run them sync, which is probably not what you want or create a public property which you bind to the `listView.IsRefreshing` property. And then set that property from the point where you are really done loading!

**Update**

As you provided your code, one way to go about this is like this:

- Set your `listView.IsRefreshing` to `pumpsManager.isLoading`
- Implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx) on your `FuelPumpsDataManager` and implement it on the `isLoading`. Note, you'll need to convert the 'isLoading' to a property. Another way to do this easier is by using the [PropertyChanged.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) NuGet package.

Now you can set the `isLoading` whenever it starts and stops loading and your ListView should show the animation accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I tried that one. I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that those methods call asynchronus methods under the hood. Is that thing gonna work correctly?

Comment: Are you using any kind of bindings or MVVM?

Comment: Yes, I'm using MVVM

Comment: Yes, I see. But right now it's not perfectly clear. So I have some kind `dataManager`, which I'm asking to update and I just created a field in that class called `isUpddting` which indicates that data is currently being updated. Could you please tell me how am I exactly supposed to bind those things?

Comment: Is there some way you can show me the code you have right now?